# Sparse on-line Gaussian Processes derivation (Parameterization Lemma)

Tags: probability-theory, stochastic-processes, statistical-inference, bayesian, gaussian

In the reference Sparse on-line Gaussian Processes

*Csató, Lehel; Opper, Manfred*, [**Sparse on-line Gaussian processes**](http://dx.doi.org/10.1162/089976602317250933), Neural Comput. 14, No. 3, 641-668 (2002). [ZBL0987.62060](https://zbmath.org/?q=an:0987.62060).

The posterior distribution is given as

- *In Bayesian learning, all information about the parameters that we wish to infer is encoded in probability distributions (Bernardo &
  Smith, 1994). In the GP framework, the parameters are functions, and
  the GP priors specify a Gaussian distribution over a function space.
  The posterior process is entirely specified by all its
  finite-dimensional marginals. Hence, let $\boldsymbol{f} =
     \{f(x_1),...,f(x_M)\}$ be a set of function values such that $f_D
     \subseteq{f}$, where $f_D$ is the set of $f(x_i) = f_i$ with $x_i$ in
  the observed set of inputs, we compute the posterior distribution
  using the data likelihood together with the prior $p_0(\boldsymbol{f})$ as*

  $$ p_{post}(\boldsymbol{f}) = \frac { P(D|\boldsymbol{f})p_0(\boldsymbol{f})} {
     \langle P(D|\boldsymbol{f}_D) \rangle_0} $$

From this equation, the mean and kernel functions is given by using parameterization lemma on page 662,

$$
\langle f_x \rangle_{post} = \langle f_x \rangle _0 + \sum_{i=1}^{N} K_0(x,x_i)q_i\\
K_{post}(x,x^{'}) = \langle f_x \rangle _0 + \sum_{i,j=1}^{N} K_0(x,x_i)R(ij)K_0(x_j,x^{'})
$$

The parameterization lemma on page 662 calculates the $q_i$ as,

$$
q_i = \frac{ \int d \boldsymbol{f}_Dp_0(\boldsymbol{f}_D)\partial_iP(D|\boldsymbol{f}_D)}
{ \int d \boldsymbol{f}_Dp_0(\boldsymbol{f}_D)P(D|\boldsymbol{f}_D)}
$$

When deriving the $q_i$ the numerator from the above equation, the author said he used the change of variable and the equation becomes

- *We can simplify the expression for qi by performing a change of variables in the numerator,$f^{'}_i=f_i-\langle f_i \rangle_0$, where
  $\langle f_i \rangle_0$ is the prior mean at $x_i$, and keeping all
  other variables unchanged $f^{'}_i=f_i, j \neq i$, leading to the
  numerator*

  $$ \int d
     \boldsymbol{f}_Dp_0(\boldsymbol{f^{'}}_D)\partial_iP(D|f^{'}_1,...,f^{'}_i+\langle
     f_i \rangle_0,...,f^{'}_i), $$

The questions are

1. Why when applying the bayesian rule to calulate the posterior
   equation is  $$ p_{post}(\boldsymbol{f}) = \frac {
      P(D|\boldsymbol{f})p_0(\boldsymbol{f})} {    \langle
      P(D|\boldsymbol{f}_D) \rangle_0} $$

not  $$ p_{post}(\boldsymbol{f}|D) = \frac  {
   P(D|\boldsymbol{f})p_0(\boldsymbol{f})} {    \langle P(D) \rangle_0}
   $$

2. Why the numerator of the $q_i$ equation  $$ num(q_i) = { \int d \boldsymbol{f}_Dp_0(\boldsymbol{f}_D)\partial_iP(D|\boldsymbol{f}_D)}
      $$

becomes after the change of variable $f^{'}_i=f_i-\langle f_i
   \rangle_0$ $$ num(q_i) = \int d   
   \boldsymbol{f}_Dp_0(\boldsymbol{f^{'}}_D)\partial_iP(D|f^{'}_1,...,f^{'}_i+\langle
   f_i \rangle_0,...,f^{'}_i) $$

not  $$ num(q_i) = \int d(\boldsymbol{f}^{'}_D + \langle
   \boldsymbol{f}_D \rangle) p_0(\boldsymbol{f^{'}}_D + \langle
   \boldsymbol{f}_D \rangle)\partial_iP(D|f^{'}_1+\langle    f_1
   \rangle_0,...,f^{'}_i+\langle    f_i \rangle_0,...,f^{'}_i+\langle   
   f_N \rangle_0) $$

I assume that the value $ \langle \boldsymbol{f}_D \rangle_0 $ is constant which is why the derivation becomes such. If so, why then $ \langle f_1 \rangle $ and $ \langle f_N \rangle_0 $ values are cancelled while $ \langle f_i \rangle_0 $ survived.

Thanks in advance.